# Почему при попытке отобразить изображение появляется ошибка «404 Not Found»?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Я использую Rails Api 5.1.6 как серверную часть и качестве клиента Angular 4. Все данные хранятся в базе данных Oracle. Изображения в Oracle хранятся в формате «Blob». Для работы с изображениями на Rails Api использую gem "paperclip".

Так вот когда я пытаюсь отобразить изображение на клиенте, появляется ошибка «404 not found». Вот ошибка в консоли:

> GET http://localhost:4200/photos/original/missing.png 404 (Not Found)
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал перейти по данной ссылке:

> http://localhost:3000/photos/original/missing.png

, но появлялась вот такая ошибка (Если нужно могу полную ошибку скинуть):

> "#ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET]
>   "/photos/original/missing.png""

JSON:

```
[
{
l_users_id: 65,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1357,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1358,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 51,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 2,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1360,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 0,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1372,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1371,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1370,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1373,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
}
]
```

photos_controller.rb:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @photos = Photo.all

    array = @photos.map do |photo|
        photo_push = {
            l_users_id:      photo.l_users_id,
            photo:           photo.photo.url
        }

        photo_push
    end

    render json: array
  end

    def show
        @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
        photo_hash = {
            l_users_id:      photo.l_users_id,
            photo:           photo.photo.url
        }

        render json: photo_hash
    end

end
```

photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "l_users_id"

  has_attached_file :photo

  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое, на стоит обратить внимание - это то, какие маршруты присутствуют в Вашем приложении. Посмотреть их можно командой

```
rails routes
```

Уверен, в списке маршрутов и правда будет отсутствовать

```
GET /photos/original/...
```

По всей видимости один из маршрутов будет выглядеть так

```
photo GET /photos/:id(.:format)                 photos#show
```

Указанный маршрут должен говорить о следующем: при обращении методом GET по url `/photos/123` отработает метод `show` в контроллере `photos`, а число 123 будет передано в этом метод в качестве параметра `id`.

Ваш метод `show` ищет по `Photo` по ид-ру 123 и отправляет *url* из найденной модели в составе json-объекта.

Другими словами, чтобы не получить 404 Ваш url должен выглядеть не так

```
http://localhost:3000/photos/original/missing.png
```

а так

```
http://localhost:3000/photos/123
```

где 123 - это ид-р модели Photo.

Но если необходимо по запросу http://localhost:3000/photos/123 получить картинку,  а не json-объект, то в методе `show` необходимо использовать метод [send_file](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) вместо render,
например:

```
send_file @photo.photo.url, :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline'
```